# SQL Distinct based on two COLUMNS and also Interchange of those two columns values should be considered as one row

Tags: java, mysql, oracle11g

SQL Distinct based on two COLUMNS and also Interchange of those two columns values should be considered as one row

As explained in the below example, Table col1, col2 and corresponding output:-

Table

```
Col 1     Col 2
A           B
A           B
B           A
C           D
D           C
E           F
```

Output

```
Col1      Col2
A           B
C           D
E           F
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more in detail what you actually want? I can't figure it out from your question.

Comment: He wants all the unique pairs of `<col1,col2>` independent of the column position. That means if `A  B` and `B  A` are two different rows you should consider them one. @Guenther

Comment: @Guenther yes i need the same result.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `greatest` and `least` along with `distinct`

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT LEAST(col1,col2),
 GREATEST(col1,col2)
FROM your_table;
```

<kbd>[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/958f4/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- if a row like `E F` does not have its "mirror image" in the table, the row should be represented in the output as is. In other words, if the last row was `F E` instead of `E F`, it shouldn't be flipped; only the row `F E`, not its mirror image, should be in the output. This requirement makes the problem more interesting - otherwise it's much easier and a solution has already been provided.
- `col1` and `col2` are non-nullable. If you may have nulls in the columns, you will need to give a more detailed of the requirement when nulls are in fact present.

Query and output:

```
with
     input_table ( col1, col2 ) as (
       select 'A', 'B' from dual union all
       select 'A', 'B' from dual union all
       select 'B', 'A' from dual union all
       select 'C', 'D' from dual union all
       select 'D', 'C' from dual union all
       select 'E', 'F' from dual union all
       select 'Z', 'H' from dual
     ),
     prep ( col1, col2, flag ) as (
       select a.col1, a.col2, case when b.col1 is null then 0 else 1 end
       from   input_table a left outer join input_table b
                            on a.col1 = b.col2 and a.col2 = b.col1
     )
select distinct
       case when flag = 0 then col1 else least   (col1, col2) end as col1,
       case when flag = 0 then col2 else greatest(col1, col2) end as col2
from   prep
;                   

COL1 COL2
---- ----
E    F
A    B
Z    H
C    D
```